# Pandas groupby(df.index) with indexes of varying size

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of dataframes `dfs = [df0, df1, ...]`. Each one of them have a `date` column of varying size (some `date`s might be in one dataframe but not the other).

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
pd.concat(dfs).groupby("date", as_index=False).sum()
```

But with date no longer being a column but an index (`dfs = [df.set_index("date") for df in dfs]`).

I've seen you can pass `df.index` to `groupby` (`.groupby(df.index)`) but `df.index` might not include all the dates.

How can I do this?

The goal here is to call `.sum()` on the `groupby`, so I'm not tied to using `groupby` nor `concat` is there's any alternative method to do so.

Comment: It would be clear if you can give an example with few data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am able to understand maybe you want something like this:

```
df = pd.concat([dfs])
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

Here's small example:

```
tmp1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-09-01','2019-09-02','2019-09-03'],'value':[1,1,1]}).set_index('date')
tmp2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-09-01','2019-09-02','2019-09-04','2019-09-05'],'value':[2,2,2,2]}).set_index('date')
df = pd.concat([tmp1,tmp2])
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```